# Error Installing PyInstaller for Python 3.7 on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, pyinstaller

I used the command `pip install pyinstaller` to installer PyInstaller for Python 3.7 on Windows 10, but the Command Prompt gave me the following errors:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes'
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cffi'
...
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------`

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MUHAMM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6_q2lzs2\pyinstaller\
```

I installed the midule `cffi`, then tried to install `pywintypes` but it was not found.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lots of modules don't support 3.7 yet as it is still quite new. Have you tried other versions or do you have to use 3.7?

Comment: I will do. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE** as of 2019-07-09

The changelog for PyInstaller==3.5 does state that they now support Python 3.7 on Windows 10.
I updated my answer to account for several necro-bumps "it works now", "the second answer should be accepted" and "downvotes" disregarding the time at which the question was asked. The second answer was not the actual solution back then, it clearly fails to state that

```
pip3.7 install PyInstaller==3.5
```

is a solid fix since 2019-07-09. The question however was asked long before that date.

---

*BEFORE* 2019-07-09

Not a solution to your problem, but [PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/) does not support Python 3.7.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid. From your link:

"Works out-of-the-box with any Python version 2.7 / 3.4-3.7"

Comment: @TommyD I believe the answer is still valid for Windows10.

Comment: @ShayNehmad The question was asked 2018-08-19 and support for Python3.7 on Windows 10 came starting 2019-07-09. So given the time the question was asked, this is the actual accepted solution. This thread needs moderator intervention... needs to be locked. I updated my answer to clarify on that...

Answer (score 11):

I got that problem.
The solution was

```
python -m pip install pip==18.1
```

then just

```
python -m pip install -U pyinstaller
```

Comment: For MacOS, you may need `python3 -m pip install -U pyinstaller`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

downgrade pip to 18.1 by typing:

```
python -m pip install pip==18.1
```

After that just run :

```
python -m pip install -U pyinstaller
```

and it should finish it with no errors. Then you can upgrade pip

```
python -m pip install –upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyinstaller for Python 3.7 version worked fine

***Please use below installation for python 3.7***

```
pip install pyinstaller==4.0 --no-build-isolation
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should Downgrade the pip first:

```
python -m pip install pip==18.1
```

then try to install pyinstaller:

```
python -m pip install -U pyinstaller
```

since there are newer pip versions, you may notice an orange color warning at the end of installation:

> **You are using pip version 18.1, however version 21.0.1 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.**

Go ahead and install the newer version of pip.